Google Cloud Run Memorystore with Redis getting timeout message
I’m trying to connect my Flask app running on Google Cloud Run to a Google Cloud Memorystore Redis instance, but I keep getting a timeout error. Both Cloud Run and Redis are in the same region and VPC network, and everything seems configured correctly, but it still won’t connect.
Setup Details:

Redis IP: 10.x.x.x
Cloud Run Region: europe-west4
Redis Region: europe-west4-a
VPC Connector: default-connector (attached to Cloud Run)

Firewall Rules:

Ingress allows traffic to Redis on port 6379 from the VPC connector IP range (100.8.0.0/28)
Egress rules allow outgoing traffic from Cloud Run to Redis

What I’ve Tried:

Checked VPC Flow logs, Enabled flow logs but haven’t seen anything indicating network traffic from Cloud Run to Redis
Checked Firewall logs, The logs show no blocks, and the rules should allow Redis traffic

Simple script I use to test, right now it always returns "Error connecting to Redis: timeout connecting to server"
from flask import Flask
import redis

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def test_redis():
    try:
        redis_host = "10.x.x.x"
        redis_port = int(6379)
        r = redis.Redis(
            host=redis_host, port=redis_port, db=0, socket_connect_timeout=20
        )
        r.ping()
        return "Successfully connected to Redis!"
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error connecting to Redis: {e}", 500


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)

Any suggestion or help is greatly appreciated, as I've tried any resource I could find and to me it feels like I've done everything the same.

try running your Flask application locally to verify that the connection works outside of Cloud Run, also have a look at this Troubleshooting guide.

@SathiAiswarya tested it using telnet using a VM on the same VPC, this works like intended

can you try increasing the timeout check this link and   have you tried creating a new VPC connector? also  check this answer changing the egress to Private ranges only
